# Java search with two text fields without typing both

Tags: java, sql-server

I've got simple Java app with two jFormattedTextFields named Width and Height and two columns in MSSQL database with exact name.
If you type Width and Height it's showing rows from database but is there any chance that it will show results after typing only one field?
Ex I'm typing Width 22 and It's showing all rows that have that field not checking Height.

Here's my code for two fields search.

```
try {
            String query = "select * from dbo.Windows where Width = '" + jFormattedTextField1.getText() + "'" + "and Heigth = '" + jFormattedTextField2.getText() + "'";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: There might be a typo in your code - Height is spelled wrong.

Comment: Oh that was just translated to English from my native language :) Thanks for pointing.

Comment: You have to check the text field for emptyness and only use the fields that are not empty.

Comment: You desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Well this one is a simple local app which will be used by one person, but I agree that SQL injection is important topic.